# Error in Binding Custom Textbox Property

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, custom-controls, prism-4

**I have created custom Textbox in Silverlight 4, MVVM and PRISM 4. The custom text box has dynamic behavior link it dynamically set TextMode to either Password or Text.**

This is working perfect. ( if i am bind TextMode static)

```
<control:PasswordTextBox x:Name="customTextBox2" Width="100" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Email}"  TextMode="Password"/>
```

This is giving me an error (if i am binding with dynamic)

```
<control:PasswordTextBox x:Name="customTextBox1" Width="100" Height="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Email}"  TextMode="{Binding WritingMode}"/>
```

following is my ViewModel code

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class UserRightsViewModel : NotificationObject, IRegionMemberLifetime
    {
 private Mode _writingMode = Mode.Text;
public Mode WritingMode
        {
            get { return _writingMode; }
            set
            {
                _writingMode = value; RaisePropertyChanged("WritingMode");
            }
        }

[ImportingConstructor]
        public UserRightsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
UserSecurity security = new UserSecurity();
            FormSecurity formSecurity = security.GetSecurityList("Admin");
formSecurity.WritingMode =  Mode.Password;
}
}
```

following is the enum

```
namespace QSys.Library.Enums
{
    public enum Mode
    {
        Text,
        Password
    }
}
```

following code for Custom PasswordTextBox

```
namespace QSys.Library.Controls
{
    public partial class PasswordTextBox : TextBox
    {
        #region Variables
        private string _Text = string.Empty;
        private string _PasswordChar = "*";
        private Mode _TextMode = Mode.Text;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// The text associated with the control.
        /// </summary>
        public new string Text
        {
            get { return _Text; }
            set
            {
                _Text = value;
                DisplayMaskedCharacters();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the character to display for password input.
        /// </summary>
        public string PasswordChar
        {
            get { return _PasswordChar; }
            set { _PasswordChar = value; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the input text mode to display for either text or password.
        /// </summary>
        public Mode TextMode
        {
            get { return _TextMode; }
            set { _TextMode = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public PasswordTextBox()
        {
            this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(PasswordTextBox_TextChanged);
            this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(PasswordTextBox_KeyDown);
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PasswordTextBox_Loaded);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers
        void PasswordTextBox_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.TextChanged += ImmediateTextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        public void PasswordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (base.Text.Length >= _Text.Length) _Text += base.Text.Substring(_Text.Length);
            DisplayMaskedCharacters();
        }
        public void PasswordTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int cursorPosition = this.SelectionStart;
            int selectionLength = this.SelectionLength;
            // Handle Delete and Backspace Keys Appropriately
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Back || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete)
            {
                if (cursorPosition < _Text.Length)
                    _Text = _Text.Remove(cursorPosition, (selectionLength > 0 ? selectionLength : 1));
            }
            base.Text = _Text;
            this.Select((cursorPosition > _Text.Length ? _Text.Length : cursorPosition), 0);
            DisplayMaskedCharacters();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void DisplayMaskedCharacters()
        {
            int cursorPosition = this.SelectionStart;
            // This changes the Text property of the base TextBox class to display all Asterisks in the control
            base.Text = new string(_PasswordChar.ToCharArray()[0], _Text.Length);
            this.Select((cursorPosition > _Text.Length ? _Text.Length : cursorPosition), 0);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I am getting following error if i am binding with dynamically.

**Set property 'QSys.Library.Controls.PasswordTextBox.TextMode' threw an exception. [Line: 40 Position: 144]**

Your answer would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Imdadhusen

Comment: What is your exception? Message?

Comment: it is only giving following error:          Set property 'QSys.Library.Controls.PasswordTextBox.TextMode' threw an exception. [Line: 40 Position: 144]

Comment: Exception always has message. I think that Binding cannot applied to usual property. You should change your TextMode to DependencyProperty

Comment: Thanks Chopikadze for quick reply, I am very new in Silverlight so i don't have much idea about this can you help me to resolve this. I appreciated your efforts.

Comment: Good Question Imdadhusen. I am also finding solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change in your PasswordTextBox class

```
public Mode TextMode
{
    get { return _TextMode; }
    set { _TextMode = value; }
}
```

to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TextMode", typeof(Mode), typeof(PasswordTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(Mode)));

public Mode TextMode
{
    get { return (Mode) GetValue(TextModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextModeProperty, value); }
}
```

You can read more here:

- [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)
- [DependencyProperty Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx)

The main paragraph from the second link is:

> A DependencyProperty supports the following capabilities in Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF):
>
> ....
>
> - The property can be set through data binding. For more information about data binding dependency properties, see How to: Bind the
>     Properties of Two Controls.

I provide links for WPF, but basically for Silverlight it's the same

Comment: Very Excellent! i got solution with help pf yours. my vote of +1